# .... $ content.children (...). fadeOut is not a function

Tags: html, jquery, drupal

I do not use this jQuery function much, I am working in drupal and I get this error

> $content.children(...).fadeOut is not a function

My code:

```
function switchElement() {
    // Clear interval
    clearInterval(interval);

    // Remove class from current tab
    jQuery('ul.checklist-select>li>a').removeClass('active');
    // Eliminar clases que hacen visibles los div
    $content.children().removeClass('show active');
    $content.children().fadeOut(300).promise().done();

    // Show
    // Buscar por enlace y seleccionar por índice
    var $tab = $tabs.find('a.nav-link')[index];
    $($tab).addClass('active');
    // Buscar por índice y agregar clase para hacerlo visible
    $($content.children()[index]).addClass('show active');
    $($content.children()[index]).fadeIn(300);

    // Reset interval
    interval = setInterval(function () { rotate(); }, 5000);
}
```

Comment: It is a method and the syntax looks correct.  What version of jQuery are you using?  Are you using a slim version?

Comment: I am using these two,    -  jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js   -   jquery-3.5.1.min.js

Comment: Could it be that the drupal is causing me some problem?

Comment: *I am using these two... slim* - you should only use one jquery include - the 2nd will overwrite any plugins you have.   Remove the `.slim.` include as the slim version doesn't include some animations.

Comment: thanks, it worked perfectly